# "No operating system found" when booting from live CD in UEFI mode on Sony Vaio with Windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I tried all the options explained in the help page regarding booting in UEFI mode, but when I boot Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio (which already contains Windows 8) in UEFI mode using my Ubuntu CD as my first boot, it is not detecting the OS on the CD.  I am getting the error:

```
No operating system found
```

Can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Disable UEFI in BIOS.

Comment: Did you already check http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system ?

Comment: Disabling UEFI in the firmware will likely result in a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode install of Linux and an EFI-mode install of Windows. It can be awkward to switch boot modes on a boot-by-boot basis, so I don't think that's a good solution *unless* you're willing to install an [EFI boot loader for Linux](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) after the fact. This is possible, but it's usually easier to get the install working in EFI mode to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a similar VAIO to what I have. If you have a partial SSD, then your hard drive is setup as a FakeRAID 0 and Ubuntu doesn't support it. You'll have to fully wipe your hard drive and start over with whichever OS(s) you want. 
You still have to disable Secure Boot and enable Legacy Boot, but once you have a hard drive in there that Ubuntu can read, you'll be fine. 
Sony has a weird BIOS setup that won't even read the Win8 OS when you enable Legacy Boot. My wife won't let me wipe this PC, so I just run Ubuntu as a Virtual Machine using VMware Player.... Worked for months trying to get around this.... Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First, I recommend you enter your firmware setup utility (usually done by pressing Del or a function key just after powering on the computer) and disabling Secure Boot. Unfortunately, the details of how to do this vary from one computer to another, so I can't be very precise about how to do it.

If that doesn't work, then you might try downloading the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) and booting from that while the Ubuntu CD is in the drive. With any luck, rEFInd will detect the Ubuntu CD and give you a boot option for it, and that will work. If you don't see the Ubuntu CD immediately, try hitting the Esc key.

If that doesn't work, try creating a bootable USB flash drive from the Ubuntu CD. It's possible that your computer will like that better than a CD.

One more point: The option to install Ubuntu within Windows (that is, using WUBI) is unsupported on EFI-based computers, which yours is. Don't try to get that working, since it's a waste of time.

Comment: It is not working by doing this. can you share a video link explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing the cd again or temporarily disabling windows as a boot option.